# Microsoft Project: summing data from a Task field into a Resource field?

Tags: vba, ms-project

In the Task Sheet, I have a custom Numbers column called "Jellybeans". Each task has a resource attached, and some number of beans gets entered into the field. So you'd have something like

Task: let loose the fnord
Resource: Alice
Jellybeans: 5

Task: open the store
Resource: Alice
Jellybeans: 3

Task: TURN IT OFF
Resource: Bob:
Jellybeans: 4

Now, in the Resource Sheet, I create another custom number field, "Total Jellybeans". I want this field to sum all of the jellybeans attached to the resources in the Task Sheet. So you'd have

Resource: Alice
Total Jellybeans: 8

Resource: Bob
Total Jellybeans: 4

--I cannot figure out how to do this--. Tasks and Resources don't really seem to talk to each other like I'd expect, and I can't find a good how-to on formula building, because I THINK that's how I need to approach this. Is there a simple way to do this that I'm missing, or is it excessively complex?

Comment: This can't be done with a formula in a customized field because a formula can only access field information for each resource--not across resources and certainly not across task assignments. You'll need to use VBA to do this calculation.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this the Project way:

- make sure your Custom Field sums up for Group Summary rows
- Group your View (or create a Grouped View!) based on Resource

[image]

That works when there's only one resource per task. The shared tasks would get their own groups - and shared Jellybeans!

Or you can do it the VBA way:

- as you can see, I'm assuming the Jellybean Custom Field is the field Number1 for both the Tasks and the Resources (two separate fields)
- in this model all the Resources get all the Jellybeans but you can add calculation there

  ```
  Sub SumUpJellybeans()

  Dim vResource As Resource
  Dim vAssignment As Assignment
  Dim vJellybeans As Long

  For Each vResource In ActiveProject.Resources

  For Each vAssignment In vResource.Assignments

      vJellybeans = vJellybeans + vAssignment.Task.Number1

  Next vAssignment

      vResource.Number1 = vJellybeans
      vJellybeans = 0

  Next vResource

  End Sub
  ```

[image]